# Running Java Application in C# NET

Tags: c#, java, .net, minecraft

I wrote an application a while ago in C# NET that basically allows the .exe I created to start/stop when the java application (Minecraft) starts and stops.

I would like to extend some more functionality to my application by basically allowing users to type commands into my console app, and in turn send these commands to the .jar file that is running.

I read something a while ago on stackoverflow that said there were some APIs that would basically let you manage Java apps inside of a C# NET app but I can't find it now.

Does anyone know how I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you launch and manage the java app from C# using the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class, you can send input from your C# app to the launched java app process via [Process.StandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, do you know if it needs to be encoded or can I just send a string?

Comment: @Brett Powell : I'm pretty sure you won't need to encode your result. I don't know much about Minecraft but I'm guessing you mean [these](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/SMP_Server_commands) sort of commands. You should be able to send the commands as just strings. Minecraft forums and wiki may have more info.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft accepts commands from system in and responds to system out.

When you start minecraft from your application you basicly creates a new process. This process has two streams, one for system out and one for system in. You need to get hold of those streams. If you send characters to the system in stream, then they will be interpreted as commands to minecraft. If you read from the system out stream then you will get minecrafts response.

Your next task would be to let your users send commands to minecraft. One way to do this would be to let your users type in commands on a web page that you store in a file. You could have a separate thread read from the file and write the commands to minecraft's system in stream.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this what you are talking about? http://www.csharp411.com/c-convert-string-to-stream-and-stream-to-string/ So I just use "using System.IO" to communicate with it? How do I "get ahold of" the streams created by the process I am launching from my application? Thank you for the help!

Comment: After looking around a little bit more, I think I got it now. Does this look right? http://pastebin.com/X8i0w7KZ Of course I can change the scope of the StreamWriter/Reader to do this properly. One question though, does the input need to be encoded for Minecraft?

Comment: I'm actually not very seasoned in .NET, but yes, this looks right. I don't think encoding is important here unless the minecraft commands have international or special characters.